# ValueError: shapes (4886,400) and (4886,400) not aligned: 400 (dim 1) != 4886 (dim 0)

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I am trying to implement a single layer neural network in Python. The shape of my training data is (4886,400). This is what I have written:

```
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot, tanh


# Class to create a neural
# network with single neuron
class NeuralNetwork():
    def __init__(self):
        # Using seed to make sure it'll
        # generate same weights in every run
        random.seed(1)


        self.weight_matrix = 2 * random.random((4886, 400)) - 1

    # tanh as activation function
    def tanh(self, x):
        return tanh(x)

        # derivative of tanh function.

    # Needed to calculate the gradients.
    def tanh_derivative(self, x):
        return 1.0 - tanh(x) ** 2

    # forward propagation
    def forward_propagation(self, inputs):
        return self.tanh(dot(inputs, self.weight_matrix))

        # training the neural network.

    def train(self, train_inputs, train_outputs,
              num_train_iterations):
        # Number of iterations we want to
        # perform for this set of input.
        for iteration in range(num_train_iterations):
            output = self.forward_propagation(train_inputs)

            # Calculate the error in the output.
            error = train_outputs - output

            # multiply the error by input and then
            # by gradient of tanh funtion to calculate
            # the adjustment needs to be made in weights
            adjustment = dot(train_inputs.T, error *
                             self.tanh_derivative(output))

            # Adjust the weight matrix
            self.weight_matrix += adjustment

            # Driver Code


if __name__ == "__main__":
    neural_network = NeuralNetwork()

    print('Random weights at the start of training')
    print(neural_network.weight_matrix)

    train_inputs = training_data
    train_outputs = training_scores.T

    neural_network.train(train_inputs, train_outputs, 10000)

    print('New weights after training')
    print(neural_network.weight_matrix)

    # Test the neural network with a new situation.
    print("Testing network on new examples ->")
    for i in test_data:
        print(neural_network.forward_propagation(i))
```

However, this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled1/dfgd.py", line 169, in <module>
    neural_network.train(train_inputs, train_outputs, 10000)
  File "untitled1/dfgd.py", line 143, in train
    output = self.forward_propagation(train_inputs)
  File "untitled1/dfgd.py", line 134, in forward_propagation
    return self.tanh(dot(inputs, self.weight_matrix))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in dot
ValueError: shapes (4886,400) and (4886,400) not aligned: 400 (dim 1) != 4886 (dim 0)
```

Hw can I fix this problem? How should I change the dimensions of my matrices? How should I determine the dimensions of my weight matrix?

Comment: maybe matrix multiplication is the problem? matrix mul: (n by m) * (m by p) --> (n by p)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some logical errors

I assume your training data have 4886 rows and 400 columns,
and let just assume training score have 4886 rows and 100 columns
In that case you are supposed to forward one row or instance at a time
(as a vector, i.e in the shape of (400, 1) and (100, 1))

Weight_matrix should be in the shape of

> (no of neurons in next layer x no of neurons in previous layer)

The shape of output layer should be equal to the shape of training_scores,
Lets assume it has a shape of `(100, 1)`
So Your weight_matrix should be in the shape of `(100, 400)`

I have done some minor tweaks,

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
#from numpy import exp, array, random, dot, tanh, newaxis


# Class to create a neural
# network with single neuron
class NeuralNetwork():
    def __init__(self, y_shape):
        # Using seed to make sure it'll
        # generate same weights in every run
        self.weight_matrix = 2 * np.random.random((y_shape,400)) - 1

    # tanh as activation function
    def tanh(self, x):
        return np.tanh(x)

        # derivative of tanh function.

    # Needed to calculate the gradients.
    def tanh_derivative(self, x):
        return 1.0 - np.tanh(x) ** 2

    # forward propagation
    def forward_propagation(self, inputs):
        # (100, 400) x (400, 1) -> (100, 1)
        return self.tanh(np.dot(self.weight_matrix, inputs))

        # training the neural network.

    def train(self, train_inputs, train_outputs,
              num_train_iterations):
        
        summed_error = 0
        # Number of iterations we want to
        # perform for this set of input.
        for iteration in range(num_train_iterations):
            # send one instance at a time
            for x, y in zip(train_inputs, train_outputs):
                output = self.forward_propagation(x)

                # Calculate the error in the output.
                error =  output - y

                # multiply the error by input and then
                # by gradient of tanh funtion to calculate
                # the adjustment needs to be made in weights
                derror_dw = error * self.tanh_derivative(output)
                #(100, 1) x (1, 400) -> (100, 400)
                adjustment = np.dot(derror_dw, x.T)

                # Adjust the weight matrix
                # add a learning rate
                self.weight_matrix -= 0.001 * adjustment
                
                #just to measure the error of each iteration
                summed_error += np.sum(0.5*(output - y)**2)/len(train_inputs)
            print(summed_error)
            summed_error = 0
                # Driver Code


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    #dummy input and output
    training_data = np.random.normal(size=(4886, 400))
    training_scores = np.random.normal(size=(4886, 100))
    
    print(training_data.shape)
    neural_network = NeuralNetwork(training_scores.shape[1])

    print('Random weights at the start of training')
    print(neural_network.weight_matrix.shape)

    # reshape the X and y to (4886, 400, 1) and (100, 1)
    # i.e make them vectors
    training_data = training_data[:, :, np.newaxis]
    training_scores = training_scores[:, :, np.newaxis]

    train_inputs = training_data
    train_outputs = training_scores

    neural_network.train(train_inputs, train_outputs, 10)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled1/dfgd.py", line 158, in <module>
    neural_network = NeuralNetwork(training_scores.shape[1])
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: @BNoor what is the shape of your training score ?

Comment: The shape is (400, )

Comment: @BNoor both training data and scores should have same number of rows